# Google Sheets - filtering with dropdown lists

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu, filtering

I have a table on one Sheet called *Data* and 3 dropdown lists in another Sheet called *Lists*.

I want the table in *Data* to be filtered depending on the values i choose from the dropdowns in *Lists*, just like if i used a filter view.

I have tried using the `QUERY` formula, but to no avail.

Any hints?

Edit: Here is the a sample [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gxkcDvJllMoTfSX_k3df1UE-kSzECtAzEvs5drktbps/edit?usp=sharing) to get an idea.

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet, showing your data, and what you would like the output to look like.  Do you want the "filtered" data, coming from Data, to be displayed on the List sheet, filtered by the values in your three dropdown lists?  Also show the query function that you tried.

Comment: I don't want the filtered data to be shown somewhere. then i will use them to calculate some metrics in the _Lists_ sheet, making it kind of a dashboard with filters and values.

Comment: the query is a generic query that returns a sum of a column in the _Data_ sheet, but has as conditions the values of the dropdowns

Comment: Yes, if you put up a sample sheet with your dropdowns, I'm sure I cana help with the query.  Perhaps something a bit like this?  Make a copy to change the dropdown values in B3, D3, and F3, and see how it changes the query...                                                       https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B5KFkRzY_O266FHrGdb8GogJpNXJwU_J8T_Zpafzl4A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what you have here is exactly what i need. i added a sample sheet to get an idea of what i want to build. have in mind the original data have a lot more rows and will need even more calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a tab to your sheet - Lists-GK.

I've used a query formula to pull selected data from your Data tab.
The query formula is built dynamically, based on the values that are selected in the three dropdown boxes, for Campaign Media, Campaign Source, and Campaign Name.

Since you haven't specified what result you want, the query formula in A11 is very simple, bringing back all columns for the data that matches the criteria:

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:J; "Select * Where B " & D7 & E7 & F7  ;0)
```

The formulas in D7, E7, and F7 are as follows:

```
=if(D6=FALSE;"       contains '"&D5&"' ";" <> '' ")
=if(E6=FALSE;" and C contains '"&E5&"' ";"")
=if(F6=FALSE;" and D contains '"&F5&"' ";"")
```

D5, E5, and F5 are the three dropdown selection cells.
D6, E6, and F6 are checkboxes, to turn each filter/criteria off, if desired.

I've also added a query criteria for a date range, if you select a start date and an end date.  And a tickbox in H6 to turn off the date criteria.

If you want to do any calculations on the data returned, you can either modify the query, to return sum(H), for example, or, use formulas to calculate values based on the data in the range that the query returns.

I also added three helper columns - in Lists column L-N - to alphabetically sort the values for your data validation dropdown lists in D5, E5, and F5.  I find that makes them easier to work with.

Let us know if this answer works for you, or if you still have an issue.
[image]

Comment: Note that your date values in Data column A appear to be just string values, not numeric dates.  If your actual data is numeric date values, that will change the query criteria very slightly in I7 and I8.  Let me know if this is a possible issue.

Comment: thank you very much! this was really great and i can work with!! something else, do you have an idea of how to multi-select in the dropdown? or if i have a way to select multiple choices, how to add them in the query?

Comment: @Nvouk, I'm not sure what you mean by multi-select in the dropdown.  Do you mean select two or more values, so the query could find any of those?  Like two different values for Campaign Media?  If you can create a couple of examples on my sheet, of the values you would like to use, I'll see what changes to make to the query...

Comment: yes, i would like to have 2 or more values selected, e.g. in Campaign Name to have 'Web - High Intent' and 'Web - Low Intent' and the query to return the data for those two selections

Comment: Have a look at Lists2-GK, in your sheet, and let me know how that works.  I added a separate switch to exclude campaign names, since you seemed to need that.

Comment: that's close to what i need, but i want it for _two or more options_. what if i had multiple selections in a single cell, separated by a comma (e.g. in cell F5 there was "Partners, Rest, app" as the cell value)? could this work somehow in the query?

Comment: Yes, can do that easily in the query.  The challenge is how to enter those values. Do you need lots of drodown lists for each crieria, or do you just know what values to type in, like "Partners, Rest, app"?  If you want dropdowns, you should do that layout yourself, and I can help assemble the query when you've done that...

Comment: have a look at Lists-GK, i have made it so that you can select multiple values in the 3 dropdowns. Considering this, how can the querys change?

Comment: @nvouk, I've created a chat room so we can discuss the design in more detail.  Can you go here?  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223635/filtering-with-dropdown-lists

Comment: please have a look at the sheet, i made some changes regarding the multi-selection